# When property object get unrooted and marked for garbage collection?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I am trying to understand GC behaviour in below implementation.

I return a new object when my property is accessed. If I access my property for a second time, will the first object be marked for garabage collection or will it will be rooted as long as my `MyClass` object is alive.

(It's a bad implementation I know, but intention is to know about GC.)

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Custom CustomProp=>new Custom();
}

public class Custom
{

}
```

Comment: Every time you access `MyClass.Custom` a new `Custom` is created. That instance will live until there are no longer any references to it. So it depends on what the thing that calls `MyClass.Custom` does with the `Custom` instance that is returned to it.

Comment: You create a new object everytime `CustomProp` is accessed. If this is good or bad design totally depends on what you're trying to achieve, it's neither good or bad in itself. What GC does with these objects now depends on where references to these objects are stored, which is up to the caller and has nothing to do with your implementation (as long as you don't store references to the created objects in your class).

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I put a disclaimer for such comments.Its not real code.I want to know what GC will do in this case.

Comment: @TRS just seen that, removed my comment.

Comment: @TRS if it's not real code, how can we give you an honest and valid answer to your question?

Comment: The GC is un-deterministic on when it runs. Only guarantee is **that** it runs. Having said this the instance may or may not have been collected.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I didnt ask when GC will run. I asked whether first object will be marked for collection.

Comment: "will the first object be marked for Garabage collection" - that isn't a thing; nothing is ever marked for GC - at least, not actively; when the GC runs, it sweeps everything and finds things that are reachable; things that aren't reachable are eligible for collection

Comment: To answer your question, you are repointing, it doesn't delete the data at the previous address, nor does it free the memory. GC will get it if not used anymore and available for collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Custom CustomProp=>new Custom();
```

is translated to a getter method by the compiler:

```
public Custom get_CustomProp()
{
    return new Custom();
}
```

So there is no reference to the created `Custom` instance stored inside your class. Nothing to worry about, you (the code you show) don't keep the GC from collecting the object.

But of course: wether the created object is eligible for GC or not depends on what the **caller** of your property does with the reference. As long as an active reference is kept somewhere, GC won't collect the object.

And - as [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478256/when-property-object-get-unrooted-and-marked-for-garbage-collection/56478420#comment99547060_56478256) commented - there is no such thing as "marking" an object for GC. An object is ready for GC (simply put) if it is no longer referenced.
The fact that your property gets called a second time has no influence on the "collectability" of the previously return instance.